# blockui is not compatible with ng-tag-input library in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, blockui, ng-tags-input

I am using ng-tag-input and ui-block together in an app. I am using auto-complete ng-tag-input. When I type 3 letter in input tag,it does not show suggested tag.

It gives error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$rootScope/inprog?p0=NaNigest
    at VALIDITY_STATE_PROPERTY (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12)
    at beginPhase (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12966:15)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12755:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.js:1:4856)
    at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4641:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4309:46)
    at BlockUI.blkUI.factory.reset (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-block-ui/dist/angular-block-ui.js:329:28)
    at BlockUI.blkUI.factory.stop (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-block-ui/dist/angular-block-ui.js:301:14)
    at Object.blkUI.factory.utils.forEachFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-block-ui/dist/angular-block-ui.js:453:19)
    at Array.blkUI.factory.utils.forEachFnHook.arr.(anonymous function) [as stop] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-block-ui/dist/angular-block-ui.js:458:15)
```

But when I removed ui-block from `app.ng-tag-input` is working fine.

controller :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput','blockUI']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
  ];

  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('tags.json');
  };
});
```

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags">
      <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
  </body>
```

I think ui-block is not compatible with ng-tag-input.please suggest me how can I overcome this issue ? [see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HMupweVxemPxDieuiJGX?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not aware of how ui-block works. I'll try to check it out later .

Answer (score 1):

in angular-block-ui.js line 594 inject the $timeout and then use it in t[fnName].apply(t, args) just like below:

```
blkUI.factory('blockUIUtils', function($timeout) {

      var $ = angular.element;

      var utils = {
        buildRegExp: function(pattern) {
          var match = pattern.match(/^\/(.*)\/([gim]*)$/), regExp;

          if(match) {
            regExp = new RegExp(match[1], match[2]);
          } else {
            throw Error('Incorrect regular expression format: ' + pattern);
          }

          return regExp;
        },
        forEachFn: function(arr, fnName, args) {
          var i = arr.length;
          while(i--) {
            var t = arr[i];
            $timeout(function(){
              t[fnName].apply(t, args);
            });

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/examples/documentation):

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function(blockUIConfig) {

 blockUIConfig.autoBlock = false;

});
```